# Java - drawing a scaled up shape with line thickness of 1

Tags: java, scale, draw, shapes, graphics2d

When you use `Graphics2D.scale();` and draw a shape, the outline thickness is also scaled.

Is there a way to draw it without the line thickness being scaled? Perhaps there's another efficient way to scale it other than using the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974178/cant-draw-thin-lines-with-java2d). It looks like you have to mess around with a Stroke object to set the right line width.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to save your drawing as a list of line vectors, and scale and render the drawing at various sizes to maintain the line thickness you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution to my own question. I've no idea how efficient it is but it works as intended:

```
Area area = new Area(myShape); //myShape is the shape I want to scale
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(2,2);
area = area.createTransformedArea(at);
graphics2d.draw(area); //graphics2d is the Graphics2D instance to do the drawing
```

Perhaps someone could enlighten me as to whether or not this is a good approach to take?